# Performance of Vue with a large array of objects

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a long list of items (460 in total) stored in `harvesters`. Here is my code in `Vue` to filter the list:

```js
computed: {
    searchHarvesters() {
      var vm = this;
      let searchTerm =this.searchInHarvesters.toLowerCase();

      let collection_filters = {};
      let col_filt_enabled = false;
      this.distinct_collections.forEach(c => {
        if(c.selected) {
          collection_filters[c.name]=true;
          col_filt_enabled =true;
        }
      });

      return this.harvesters.filter(h => {

        let validSearch = (h.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          h.db_collection_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm) ||
          h.source_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm));
        return (
          col_filt_enabled ? 
          (typeof(collection_filters[h.db_collection_name])!== "undefined"  &&  validSearch):
          validSearch
        );

      });
    }
  }, 

...
methods:{
    debounceInput: _.debounce(function (e) {
      this.searchInHarvesters = e.target.value;
    }, 500)
  },
...
```

Here is the HTML element:

```html
<form class="uk-search uk-search-default uk-float-right">
  <span class="uk-search-icon-flip" uk-search-icon></span>
  <input class="uk-input" type="search" placeholder="Search..." v-on:input="debounceInput">
</form>
```

When I put a term to the input to filter the list, it works fine; however, when I clear the input, it gets like 5s to display the full list, which is quite slow.
How can I make Vue work faster?
Thanks.

Comment: By looking at the devtools and look at what it is doing. A filter like this on 500 elements will not take 5 seconds, not even on a mobile phone. Creating 500 * how many elements/components may do that though. Since you have not included that code, I can't really tell if that may be the case. Try replacing the `v-for` over `searchHarvesters` with simply `{{ searchHarvesters }}`, to make sure it is still calculated, and printed, but no html elements have to be made. Does this speed things up... a lot?

Comment: @Sumurai8 yes, it speeds up a lot.
Then mightbe the rendering code in `v-for` is too heavy?

Comment: In that case, look into a solution that either limits the number of elements that can be shown at once (e.g. limit to at most 100 rows or something, displaying a warning if there are more rows), or look into a solution where only the elements on screen are rendered, while the rest is an empty div with a height. I believe the technique is called "virtual scroll" and there are several libraries for it.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if this is the bottleneck, as 5s does seem quite a lot for just 500 items.

You can "turn off" reactivity for large lists given that you won't be editing any of their item information with `Object.freeze`, so if it is just listing you could do this:

1. Disable reactivity for the total items.

```js
this.harvesters = Object.freeze(this.harvesters);
```

2. Disable reactivity for returned items in the computed prop:

```js
const matches = this.harvesters.filter(h => {
  // ...
});

return Object.freeze(matches);
```